# How do I print something whenever two lines meet in matplotlib with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, lines

Heres my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import urllib

API = 'http://api.example.com'
data = urllib.request.urlopen(API)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = df['x'].tolist()
y1 = df['y1'].tolist()
y2 = df['y2'].tolist()

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
ax1.plot(x, y1, label='y1')
ax1.plot(x, y2, label='y2')
plt.show()
```

So basically I've plotted two lines:

```
ax1.plot(x, y1, label='y1')
ax1.plot(x, y2, label='y2')
```

Assuming that the chart is live and updating. I want python to print a warning message whenever the lines meet, with another condition that it will only print a warning message for 100 times.

Here's what I got so far:

I defined the warning_message function to print a warning message.

```
def warning_message():
    print("Warning!")
```

I've also done the other condition wherein it will only print a warning message for 100 times.

```
count = 100
while count != '0':
    warning_message()
    count -= 1
```

What's missing inside this while loop is the condition that it will only print the warning message whenever the lines meet.
Does anyone know how do it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the lines share the same x data, it's rather easy to compare their y data.
Simply asking whether `y2 > y1` is enough.

```
import numpy as np

y1 = np.array([1,2,3])
y2 = np.array([0,1,3.1])

if np.any(y2>y1):
    print("warning")
```

In order to make this work in your script, don't use `.tolist()` but keep the data as numpy arrays, i.e. `y1 = df['y1'].values`.

---

It seems some more guidance is needed. So to check for every possible case, y2 comes from above y1, or from below y1, you may do the following:

```
import numpy as np

y1 = np.array([1,2,3])
y2 = np.array([0,1,2.9])+1

c = y2>y1
if (np.any(c) and not np.all(c)) or (np.any(~c) and not np.all(~c)):
    print("warning")

if np.all(c) or np.all(~c):
    #reset counter here
    pass
```

Comment: This code prints a message only when the line y2 is over the line y1. It doesn't print a message when the line y1 is over the line y2. It also only prints one message(only when the line y2 is over the line y1), it prints one and done. It doesn't print for future line crossovers. I want it to print a message every time the lines cross/meets. Edit: I didn't downvote your answer. Wasn't me.

Comment: There is no need to down vote his interpretation of what the original poster was asking.  Simply inform the answer of what you were expecting.

Comment: This answer shows the concept. To have it print it several times you need to include it in your plotting loop. To check for y1 being greater than y2 you can of course check for that condition. The question isn't perfectly clear about that point, but implicitely to have the lines meet, they would need to be separated at some point beforehands. So you may want to check the condition for the case that applies. I updated the answer to include every possible case.

Comment: Worked :) Thanks!